# MySql Connectivity issue on wamp

Tags: joomla, wamp

I am USing Wamp server to make joomla project . I have completed the project and it was working fine but after a day i checked it so it wasnt opening and showing following error

.Error: Failed to start application: Could not connect to MySQL server.

Comment: Is MySQL or mariaDB running? What colur is WAMPServer's wampmanager icon in the system tray

Comment: Did you check the MySQL Log?

Comment: My Sql Log showing this
2018-04-21T14:56:06.503167Z 0 [Warning] InnoDB: Resizing redo log from 2*3072 to 2*4096 pages, LSN=2552543
2018-04-21T14:56:06.743007Z 0 [Warning] InnoDB: Starting to delete and rewrite log files.
2018-04-21T14:56:20.681442Z 0 [Warning] InnoDB: New log files created, LSN=2552543
What does it means?

Comment: This is a fairly normal initialise of MySQL and INNODB

Comment: what to do now?

Comment: Can you see the database using phpMyAdmin?

Answer (score 0):

It might have corrupted due to some reason. You can try once restarting the mysql service through wamp using stop and start.

Comment: You can also check logs of mysql for more details about error.

Comment: I had  restarted but same issue coming